# How to call a method at the right time?

Tags: android, retrofit

There is a simple request. In the condition, I catch error 403.

```
.enqueue(new Callback<NewOrderResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<NewOrderResponse> call, Response<NewOrderResponse> response) {
                        if (response.code() == 403) {
                            connect.login(manager, manager.getphone(), manager.getpass());
                            connect.reconnectNewOrder(manager.getsessionid(), new Gson().toJson(newOrderRequest));
                        }
                    }
```

And I call the login(***connect.login(manager, manager.getphone(), manager.getpass());***) method:

```
 .login(login, passFromSms)
                .enqueue(new Callback<AuthResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<AuthResponse> call, Response<AuthResponse> response) {
                        if (response.code() == 200) {
                            // Save id session
                            Headers header = response.headers();
                            List<String> cookieList = header.values("Set-Cookie");
                            _jsessionid = (cookieList.get(0).split(";"))[0];

                            manager.savesession(_jsessionid);

                        }
                    }
```

In this method, I have to save the new session id.

But as soon as the program enters the method **.login (login, passFromSms)**

and executes it, it immediately exits the method (and does not save the session for me) and executes the method:

**connect.reconnectNewOrder (manager.getsessionid (), new Gson (). toJson (newOrderRequest));**

And it turns out that this method is executed with the old session.

- Program execution is not sequential, why so?
- What is the problem ? What can I do to make the program run sequentially or what are the options at all?

Comment: Maybe this can be solved by calling a method in the 200 response block? Can you paste your entire class

Comment: No, I enter to connect.login()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call your next method in the response block:

```
 .login(login, passFromSms)
                .enqueue(new Callback<AuthResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<AuthResponse> call, Response<AuthResponse> response) {
                    if (response.code() == 200) {
                        // Save id session
                        Headers header = response.headers();
                        List<String> cookieList = header.values("Set-Cookie");
                        _jsessionid = (cookieList.get(0).split(";"))[0];

                        manager.savesession(_jsessionid);

                        // Call method here, handle failed response appropriately
                        reconnect(_jsessionid);

                    }
                }

//...

// The method you will call from the 200 response block
private void reconnect(int sessionId) {
    connect.reconnectNewOrder (sessionId, new Gson (). toJson(newOrderRequest));
}
```

Comment: Good software design isnt always convenient to work with.

Answer (score 0):

when you enqueue a call it runs on another thread and you can't control which thread to run first so you have to wait until `login` call be executed and inside its callback call `reconnectNewOrder` or instead of `enqueue()` use `execute()` method of retrofit